# Handle multiple Ajax request on pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

retrieve data :

```
<div class="manifestations">
  @include('data.php')
</div>
```

and this is my code :

```
<script>
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
            if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                getManifestations(page);
            }
        }
    });


    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#spinCard').hide();
    });

    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#spinCard').show();
    });

    app.ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function (e) {
            getManifestations($(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1]);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    function getManifestations(page) {
        $.ajax({
            url : '?page=' + page,
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('.manifestations').html(data);
            location.hash = page;
        }).fail(function () {
           alert('Manifestations could not be loaded.');
        });
    }
</script>
```

if a user clicks multiple times sequentially on next ajax keeps jumping between pages numbers like this #5 #6 #5 #6 #5 ...
is there a way to prevent this ?

ps removing this :

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
            if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                getManifestations(page);
            }
        }
    });
```

prevent sending multiple request is there any solution to modify the above code and make it send one request at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way this can be prevented is by not allowing one more ajax call until the first one is complete

```
 function getManifestations(page) {
    if(! $('#spinCard').hasClass('data-loading')) {
        $('#spinCard').addClass('data-loading')
       $.ajax({
            url : '?page=' + page,
            dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('.manifestations').html(data);
            location.hash = page;
        }).fail(function () {
           alert('Manifestations could not be loaded.');
        }).always(function () {
            $('#spinCard').removeClass('data-loading')
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Using a global variable for this is not optimal. Use something that has more context, like a CSS class "loading" on the element in question. Or a closure variable inside `getManifestations()`. Also, you *always* want to re-set the variable, so it makes more sense to do in inside the `.always()` callback instead of in both `.done()` and `.fail()`.

Comment: Updated as per the comments, Thank you.